# How to output a prediction in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, tensorflow

I am trying to use a Tensorflow DNN for a [Kaggle Competion](https://www.kaggle.com/c/allstate-claims-severity). The data is about 100 columns of categorical data, 29 columns of numerical data, and 1 column for the output. What I did was I split it into training and testing with X and y using Scikit's train test split function, where X is a list of each rows without the "id" or the value that needs to be predicted, and y is the value that is needed to be predicted. I then built the model, shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
import pickle
with open('pickle.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    trainX, trainy, testX, testy = pickle.load(f)
trainX = np.array(trainX)
trainy = np.array(trainy)
trainy = trainy.reshape(trainy.shape[0], 1)
testX = np.array(testX)
testy = np.array(testy)
print (trainX.shape)
print (trainy.shape)
testX = testX.reshape(testX.shape[0], 130)
testy = testy.reshape(testy.shape[0], 1)
print (testX.shape)
print (testy.shape)
n_nodes_hl1 = 256
n_nodes_hl2 = 256
n_nodes_hl3 = 256

n_classes = 1

batch_size = 100


# Matrix = h X w
X = tf.placeholder('float', [None, len(trainX[0])])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def model(data):

    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([trainX.shape[1], n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    # (input_data * weights) + biases

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output


def train(x):

    pred = model(x)
    #loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred - y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

    epochs = 1

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        print ('Beginning Training \n')
        for e in range(epochs):
            timeS = time.time()
            epoch_loss = 0

            i = 0
            while i < len(trainX):

                start = i
                end = i + batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(trainX[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(trainy[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i += batch_size
            done = time.time() - timeS
            print ('Epoch', e + 1, 'completed out of', epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss, "\nTime:", done, 'seconds\n')
        correct = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(pred, 1), tf.arg_max(y, 1))
        acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print("Accuracy:", acc.eval({x:testX, y:testy}))


train(X)
```

Output for 1 epoch:

```
Epoch 1 completed out of 1 loss: 1498498282.5 
Time: 1.3765859603881836 seconds

Accuracy: 1.0
```

I do realize that the loss is very high, and I am using 1 epoch just for testing purposes, and yes, I know my code is quite messy. But all I want to do is print out a prediction. How would I do that? I know that I need to feed a list of features for X, but I just don't understand how to do it. I also don't quite understand why my accuracy is at 1.0, so if you have any suggestions for that, or any ways to change my code, I would be more that happy to listen to any ideas. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

To get a prediction you just have to evaluate `pred`, which is the operation that defines the output of the model.

How to do it? With `pred.eval()`. But you need an input to evalaute its prediction, so you have to provide a `feed_dict` dictionary to `eval()` with the sample (or samples) you want to process.

The resulting code looks like:

```
predictions = pred.eval(feed_dict = {x:testX})
```

Notice how this is very similar to `acc.eval({x:testX, y:testy})`, because the idea is the same. You have an operation (`acc` in this case) which needs some input to be evaluated, and you can evaluate it either by calling `acc.eval()` or `sess.run(acc)` with the corresponding `feed_dict` with the necessary inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use the existing session while training (between iterations):

```
print (sess.run(model, {x:X_example}))
```

where X_example is some numpy example tensor.

Comment: what is model here?

Comment: Look at the top. The model is a function that builds the graph for tensorflow computation. The {x:X_example} is then the 'feed_dict' argument, which puts  real data into the so-called tensorflow "placeholders".

Answer (score 1):

The below line will give you probability scores for every class for example is you 3 classes then the below line will give you a array of shape of 1x3 
Considering you want prediction of a single data point `X_test` you can do the following:

```
output = sess.run(pred, {x:X_test})
```

the maximum number in the above variable `output` will be you prediction so for that we will modify the above statement :

```
output = sess.run(tf.argmax(pred, 1), {x:X_test})
print("your prediction for X_test is :", output[0])
```

Other thing you can do is :

```
output = sess.run(pred, {x:X_test})
output = np.argmax(output)
print("your prediction for X_test is :", output)
```